# How do I make a 3D line object in MatLab from xyz coordinates such that it is usable in a Procrustes Analysis?

Tags: matlab, matrix, graphics, 3d, linear-algebra

I have a set of data made up of coordinates x, y, and z which I plot to create a 3D line. I want to perform a Procrustes Analysis to find the similarity between the shape of this 3D line and another default shape. When I try to use any shape analysis functions or Procrustes functions, it gives me an invalid handle error on the 3D plot input that I created to hold it, i.e. 'myLine'. How can I convert this 3D plot of coordinates to a usable object for Procrustes or some other function?

[3D line created from the coordinates in code below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1GKE.jpg)

> myLine = plot3(GPS(:,8),GPS(:,9),GPS(:,10))

Below is the shape analysis function I'm trying to work with

```
function [f,g]=ShapeAnalysis(f,g)
% SHAPEANALYSIS(F,G) Plots the parameterised curves before and after
% each stage of translating, scaling and aligning. Outputs are
% parameterised curves ready for Procustes shape analysis.

LW = 'LineWidth'; FS = 'FontSize';
% Plot orignal
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(f,'r',LW,2), hold on, axis equal, plot(g,'k',LW,2)
title('Orignal',FS,16)

% Translate mean to 0.
f = f-mean(f); g = g-mean(g);
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(f,'r',LW,2), hold on, axis equal, plot(g,'k',LW,2)
title('After translation',FS,16)

% Scale so RMSD is 1.
f = f/norm(f); g = g/norm(g);
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(f,'r',LW,2), hold on, axis equal, plot(g,'k',LW,2)
title('After scaling',FS,16)

% Align major axis.
subplot(2,2,4)
% Find argument of major axis.
[~,fxmax]=max(abs(f)); [~,gxmax]=max(abs(g));
rotf=angle(f(fxmax)); rotg=angle(g(gxmax));
% Rotate both so major axis lies on the +ve real axis.
x = chebfun('x',[0,2*pi]);
f = exp(-1i*rotf)*f(mod(x+fxmax,2*pi));
g = exp(-1i*rotg)*g(mod(x+gxmax,2*pi));
plot(f,'r',LW,2), hold on, axis equal, plot(g,'k',LW,2)
title('After aligning',FS,16), hold off

end
```

edit: I guess an easier way to put it is how can I refer to the line created with one variable such that if I wrote 'plot(myLine)', where myLine = the line created by plot3(GPS(:,8),...), it will create the same line. This way I can pass the one variable to a comparison function. (to be clear, I am not having a problem with graphing the line, only manipulating it with only a reference to coordinates and no line equation)

edit: I am trying to pass myLine into shape analysis, along with say the equation for a circle to compare how closely myLine is to the second entry. So I enter:

```
>>myLine = plot3(GPS(:,8),GPS(:,9),GPS(:,10))
>>ShapeAnalysis(myLine,circle(0,0,1))
```

After entering this, I get the following error:

```
Error using plot
Invalid handle.

Error in ShapeAnalysis (line 9)
    plot(f,'r',LW,2), hold on, axis equal, plot(g,'k',LW,2)
```

I hope this clears my question up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost answered your own question: "How can I convert this 3D plot of coordinates to a usable **object**...?" Like any object, you need a reference to it for manipulation:

```
myLine = plot3(GPS(:,8),GPS(:,9),GPS(:,10))
```

Now you can pass around myLine and see what you can do with it.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. It gives me an invalid handle error when I try to use this method. Is this an error on my part? I use the function I provided and pass 'myLine' along with another line to it but it gives the handle error i mentioned in the question.

Comment: Based on your edit- When you want to replot your line, you have to give it the properties you are looking for. For example, "myLine" has XData, YData, and ZData which is what you would like to plot. Depending on which version of Matlab you are working with when you want to replot use either: plot3(myLine.XData, myLine.YData, myLine.ZData) or plot3(get(myLine, 'XData'), get(myLine, 'YData'), get(myLine, 'ZData')). Look into OOP if you are confused about this. (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html)

Comment: I can replot perfectly right now, I just need to figure out how to get an object that the above function will accept. Do I need to convert it to an equation of the line?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to post the errors you are getting. Also, if you give specific (code) examples of what you tried when posting questions on here it would help answer your question. If you are trying to pass myLine into ShapeAnalysis, you just need to update the args it takes in and pass it normally. (Not sure if that is your question).

Comment: Sorry, edit added. Yes, I am trying to pass this 3D line along with another line to compare in the above shape analysis function.

Comment: Well plot3() produces a 3D line object. plot() is also a built-in function that produces a 2D line object, so it is meaningless to pass in a 3D line object. Even if myLine were a 2D object, plot() takes in the X and Y Data, not the object handle. If you just want to compare the X and Y data (excluding Z data) you would pass in plot(get(f, 'XData'), get(f, 'YData')). Why would you not use plot3() again? I think it would be to your advantage to put a breakpoint at that line. Look at what 'f' holds. It will have all of the data of a 3D line object

Comment: Here is the doc page with those properties https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chartline-properties.html

Comment: your line 9 would look like this for the 3D case: plot3(get(f, 'XData'), get(f, 'YData'), get(f, 'ZData'), 'r', LW, 2)